# Enter and Exit on same bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

new to Trading View and Pinescript. Trying to code entry on the open of certain bar and exit on the close of the same bar. And to make it on a certain day of week. This is to backtest different days of week.
Firstable I tried to backtest using hour timeframe to open and close on a certain hour of day but then understood that this is not correct because different papers have different available hours and it can change even inside the history of one certain paper. Then I tried to code on a day timeframe, but now Pinescrupt only enters on the next day and close a week later if I use this code:

```
//@version=5 strategy
("Моя стратегия", overlay=true)

long_entry = dayofweek(time) == 2 // Monday
long_exit = dayofweek(time) == 2 // Monday

if (long_entry) 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)   
if (long_exit) 
    strategy.close("Long")`
```

And if I use "process_orders_on_close = true" it enters on the end of the current day and exits a week later. How can I enter on the open of a certain day and exit on the close of the same day?
I need to exit exactly on close of the sabe bar not on open of the next bar to avoid gaps

Comment: that's how the market orders behave. https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#market-orders
you can override it only with this parameters https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#altering-calculation-behavior

Comment: I've read these instructions but still can't understand if it is possible somehow (with limit or market orders) to make this script that I want

Answer (score 0):

with default market orders behaviour: (opening position on the next bar)
closing position on the same bar with `immediately` parameter

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = dayofweek == dayofweek.thursday
shortCondition = dayofweek == dayofweek.friday
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (shortCondition)
    strategy.close_all(immediately = true)
```